# What is the correct way to free large array memory

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working with image processing with canvas.

Users will select 10 photos (normally large-resolution photos) each time, then a script will process these photos before uploading them to a server.

The process will create large arrays and consumes lots of memory. So I am wondering **which of the options listed below is the correct way to free memory**.

**option 1:** do nothing, leave GC to handle the memory use

```js
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    var bigArray = new Array(20000000);
    //do something with bigArray
}
```

**option 2:** set to null

```js
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    var bigArray = new Array(20000000);
    //do something with bigArray

    bigArray=null;  
}
```

**option 3:** set to null after freeing array contents

```js
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    var bigArray=new Array(20000000);

    //do something with bigArray

    bigArray=[];
    bigArray=null;  
}
```

**option 4:** set to null after setting array length to zero

```js
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    var bigArray=new Array(20000000);
    //do something with bigArray
    bigArray.length=0;
    bigArray=null;  
}
```

Comment: setting it to null is all that is required. The other options (assigning empty array, etc) provide no benefit as the heap will be cleared at next GC anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just tested, bigArray = []; bigArray = null; and bigArray.length = 0; all work fine to free the large array properly. According to your answer, do you mean bigArray = null will be the preferable one between above three methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bigArray` will get garbage collected completely if all references to it are lost. With:

```
 bigArray = [];
```

the original reference gets lost, and the array gets garbage collected, `bigArray` points to a new empty array. With:

```
bigArray = null;
```

the reference gets lost too. With

```
bigArray.length = 0;
```

the array will loose the reference to all its stored values, just the array itself stays in memory.

Now what you should do (instead of creating a leaking a variable outside of a loop and manually manage its dereferencing):

Just define the scope properly, so that it will automatically gets unreferenced:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let bigArray = new Array(20000000);

   //do something with bigArray
   //...
   // array gets recycled here
}
```

---

Sidenote:

`Array(20000000)` is not a big array until you fill it with actual values.

Comment: Sidenote is wrong, try to open memory profile of chrome, BEFORE and AFTER setting in console:

`var p = new Array(1000000)` this will eat ~8mb of memory

Comment: @mosè you are definetly missinterpreting the console

Comment: maybe are you missing something too: http://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/07/24/javascript-array-object-sizes.html

Comment: Thank you @Mosè Raguzzini. Just tested, bigArray = []; bigArray = null; and bigArray.length = 0; all work fine to free the large array properly. I have an extra question, after doing some things with bigArray, the bigArray is not needed any more, we just want to free its memory, in this case, which of above methods ( bigArray = []; bigArray = null; and bigArray.length = 0;) is recommended?  Or there will be no significant difference between them? For compatibility reason, I cannot use let statement for now.

Comment: For your discussion of Sidenote, I also tested. It seems that it depends on bowsers. In firefox, new Array(20000000) will not consume memory while Chrome will eat about 8MB

Comment: @xwuwo they do almost the same thing (see my answer). Maybe null or empty array are the more semantic options as the real difference is how another dev will read your code to understand it. About the sidenote: yes, different browsers engine behave differently.

Answer (score 3):

Setting it to null or setting it to an empty array, undefined empty string or other option will all work as it make data eligible for garbage collection.

**Notice:**

In your first example (using `var`) will not make it eligible for garbage collection as you are storing a reference from the global scope  to your `var`:

```js
for(i=0;i<10; i++){
   var pippo = "TEST";
}
console.log(pippo);
```

Comment: Thank you for your remanding. Yes, 'var' statement in example indeed will occupy memory unless you manually call GC in console. Should use 'let'

Answer (score 1):

Hi,

```
bigArray = null;
```

if you want to reuse the variable for an other type

```
bigArray = [];
```

if you want to reuse it as array

```
delete bigArray;
```

if you've done with this variable